# vim YouCompleteMe is only completing words currently in the buffer

Tags: python, vim, ubuntu-14.04, youcompleteme

I installed youcompleteme according to the instructions on the github page. I have the latest vim taken from the official vim github, with python 2 (no python 3), and youcompleteme is completing words that are are already in the buffer, however I am not getting any "semantic completion" (I believe it is called.) It won't autocomplete builtin python libraries.

I've got no idea how to even diagnose this. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the plugin's issue tracker to find similar issues there. Setting path might include more files in search option. You can try setting path.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an issue tracker or a mailing list. Use those.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been very late but you need to hit a trigger for semantic completion to happen, for example,`<Ctrl-Space>`. This did not work for my machine due to shortcut conflict but you can customize trigger to something else, like after typing certain amount of letters or certain character.
[More Info](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/FAQ#the-completions-are-just-words-from-my-buffer-how-do-i-get-the-right-functions-listed)